# vmdk mounting on osx

Tags: macos, vmware

[How can I mount vmdk in 10.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791167/how-can-i-mount-vmdk-in-10-7) seems to be outdated.  what is the recommended way to mount vmdk volumes in osx 10.10 yosemite and vmware fusion 7, short of starting vmware fusion itself?

(vmdk is also used by virtualbox, so presumably the format is reasonably open.  fuse can still be sideloaded from https://osxfuse.github.io/ .  but beyond this, I have no idea.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For macOS 10.7 (64-bit Lion) to macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) you may use [this free application](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/vd-mounter-mac-free/#features).

Due to recent changes by Apple to remove kernel extensions, there is no easy way to use new file systems. This has impacted macFuse and other 3rd party filesystems.

There is currently no known way to mount a vmdk in newer macOS 10.12 to 13 (Ventura).